# locked vs unlocked account in Ganache, what is the password?

Tags: accounts

I still don't understand this issue of locked and unlocked account, so I decided to test it with Ganache. I can transfer ETH from one account to another using sendTransaction with no problem. So I used web3js to lock an account, and then it gave an error when I tried to transfer ETH from this account that I locked. That means I was able to successfully lock the account. But I don't know what the password for these accounts is, nor how the password issue works. Does every account, when created, need a password? This password is recorded in the node that created the account? Is this the password that MetaMask asks to log in? In the case of Ganache, is it possible to see the password for the account? If anyone can clarify this issue of locking/unlocking an account, it would help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[Ganache](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache) has the parameter `--wallet.passphrase` that allows setting the passphrase for unlocking the accounts.

From the [command line options](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache#startup-options)

```
--wallet.passphrase                   Passphrase to use when locking accounts.
                                      deprecated aliases: --passphrase
```

Comment: Are you sure that is it the same thing? I was recently reading Gavin Wood's Mastering Ethereum where he explains that passphrase is a secondary source of entropy that, along with the 12 words, creates the seed for the HD wallet. The password would be a way to lock (encrypt) the file where the wallet keeps the private keys.

Comment: @JoãoPauloMorais I've update the question with the definition of the command line option given by Ganache developers in the README file. It seems un unfortunate but in Ethereum usually the "passphrase" in HDWallets isn't used, and some wallets don't support it.